# Is there a plugin for Sublime Text that folds lines inside of a line you just unfolded?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

When I unfold a line in Sublime Text, I don't like how the lines contained inside are already unfolded. I want to use a plugin that fixes this. Below are some images that help explain what I'm looking for.

Imagine a variable `user` folded like this in Sublime Text:

[image]

When I unfold the `user` variable, I want my code to look like...

[image]

And if I unfold `user.friends`, I want my code to look like...

[image]

## Is there a plugin like this that exists for Sublime Text?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: No.  Sadly.  I would also like persistent code folding.  But no to that as well.